# How to detect Supported Camera resolution in diffrent devices

Tags: flutter, camera

i am using camera: ^0.10.5+3 plugin for video recording in my flutter application. but i want to display the resolutions in video recording screen which are only supported for that device i tried to get the default camera resolution in devices but cant get anything can anyone help here or can suggest anything? how to get the supported resolutions

i have shown in gallery like if i choose 2160p resolution from resolution preset and save that video to gallery in video info it showing 1080p resolution.

here is example how i have used this plugin.
camera initialization

```
 ResolutionPreset currentResolutionPreset = ResolutionPreset.high;
    final CameraController cameraController = CameraController(
          cameraDescription,
          currentResolutionPreset,
          imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.jpeg,
        );
    try {
      await cameraController.initialize();
      await Future.wait([
        cameraController
            .getMinExposureOffset()
            .then((value) => _minAvailableExposureOffset = value),
        cameraController
            .getMaxExposureOffset()
            .then((value) => _maxAvailableExposureOffset = value),
        cameraController
            .getMaxZoomLevel()
            .then((value) => _maxAvailableZoom = value),
        cameraController
            .getMinZoomLevel()
            .then((value) => _minAvailableZoom = value),
      ]);
      print("cameracontroller---${cameraController.value.previewSize}");
      _currentFlashMode = controller!.value.flashMode;
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      print('Error initializing camera: $e');
    }
```

dropdown to show resolution

```
DropdownButton<ResolutionPreset>(
           dropdownColor: Colors.black87,
           underline: Container(),
           value: currentResolutionPreset,
           items: [
           for (ResolutionPreset preset
           in resolutionPreset)
           DropdownMenuItem(
           value: preset,
                child: Text(
                   // preset.name,
                     _createList(preset),
                     style: const TextStyle(
                                 color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                           )
```

to get the ResolutionPreset value

```
_createList(ResolutionPreset preset) {
    print("preset-----==-----$preset");
    if (preset.toString().split('.')[1].toUpperCase() == "LOW") {
      return "240p";
    } else if (preset.toString().split('.')[1].toUpperCase() == "MEDIUM") {
      return "480p";
    } else if (preset.toString().split('.')[1].toUpperCase() == "HIGH") {
      return "720p";
    } else if (preset.toString().split('.')[1].toUpperCase() == "VERYHIGH") {
      return "1080p";
    } else if (preset.toString().split('.')[1].toUpperCase() == "ULTRAHIGH") {
      return "2160p";
    }else if (preset.toString().split('.')[1].toUpperCase() == "MAX") {
      return "MAX";
    }

    return preset.toString().split('.')[1].toUpperCase();
  }
```

now i want to show only supported resolution in dropdown list.